# When using emacsclient, how can I open the file in the active buffer?

Tags: buffers, window, hooks, files, emacsclient

When I open a file with emacsclient without invoking -c, Emacs visits the file in a new buffer in the background while leaving my current window configuration in place.  I'd like to change this, e.g. to open the file in whichever buffer is currently active.

Comment: I always use `emacsclient -a ''` to open files in an existing emacs frame (created for the first time using `emacsclient -a '' -c`) and files always open in one of the visible windows, never as hidden buffers. Can you verify if you see the same behavior after you move the `init.el` and/or `.emacs` files to something like `init.elbkp`/`.emacsbkp`?

Comment: If you need `server-start` in `init.el`, you will need to create a new `init.el` with the minimal required code for your server setup after you move the original file to a backup file.

Comment: Ahh, thank you for explaining that this is the default behavior.  I did a bisecting debug and found that I had not configured my saveplace package correctly.

Comment: `emacsclient --no-wait ...` might be of help.